# Python scapy import error

Tags: python, scapy

If I include following line in my python source file

```
from scapy.all import *
```

I get this error

```
from scapy.all import *
ImportError: No module named all
```

Which is true in Console and IDLE, but not eclipse.
I am very much confused why this is happening.
Can some one help me out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this may be a problem with your version:

If you are using Scapy v1.X:

```
from scapy import *
```

Otherwise, with Scapy V2.X+

```
from scapy.all import *
```

Is the way to go.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Scapy v2: `from scapy.all import *` whereas on scapy v1 `from scapy import *`

Answer (score 11):

If scapy is not installed in your system, then you can use this command to install scapy:

`sudo apt-get install python-scapy`

Comment: This would work for Debian based systems, use the appropriate package manager for your version of Linux.

Comment: Also available via `pip install scapy`

Answer (score 2):

Delete any file named scapy.py

Comment: my file name was scapy.py and it was throwing above , renaming file works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I want to contribute to this problem. Watch for files named "scapy" in your directory where u are using your script. I had one named "scapy.py" and obviously python tries to include from ".". I removed script and: import scapy.all import * works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think there was a change is scapy somewhere. I put the following code in my scapy projects so it remains compatible.

```
try:
    import scapy
except ImportError:
    del scapy
    from scapy import all as scapy
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux get this folder:

```
/usr/share/pyshared
```

If you not found `scapy` you must download and install this, for example for Ubuntu you can found this:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/python-scapy/download

and download package and install this pack about 300 kb.

Answer (score 0):

If scapy is not installed, please install with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scapy
```

Answer (score -2):

> > > from kamene.all import *
> > >       WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?). This affects only IPv6
> > >
> > > Use this one instead of scapy.all