# scapy not found

Tags: python, scapy

I have installed scapy 2.2.0 with macport. I imported it to my python code, following [these instructions](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#overview) (from scapy.all import *)
And when running my python code  I have

```
from scapy.all import *
ImportError: No module named scapy.all
```

But when i run scapy in command line it's launch normally.

Any clue?

Comment: Do you found the solution for this./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may be running into this issue.

[Python scapy import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273936/python-scapy-import-error)

Try this and let me know if that solves your problem.