# No module named 'scapy' when it is clearly installed

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I'm running a simple python script, `script.py` on MacOS and I receive the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy'`. This is what I've done:

- Tried importing scapy in the script with:

  - `from scapy import *`
  - `from scapy.all import *`
  - `import scapy`
- Installed scapy with `pip3 install scapy` (now returning `Requirement already satisfied: scapy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`).
- Tried running my script with:

  - `python3 script.py`
  - `python3.7 script.py`
- Made sure I don't have a file called `scapy.py` in my script's directory.

I've tried everything in these posts and none have worked: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610064/scapy-all-import-does-not-work) 
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273936/python-scapy-import-error)

Comment: Have you tried installing this in a virtualenv? This is the canonical way to fix `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: Haven't tried that. Will do thanks.